# Ext.dispatch from within itemTap listener?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

A similar question was answered here: [How to add itemtap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337404/how-to-add-itemtap)

But when I try to move my `Ext.dispatch()` code from `onItemDisclosure:` to `listeners: {itemtap:}`, it doesn't work.

The Ext.dispatch originally lived here:

```
    onItemDisclosure: {
        scope: this,
        handler: function (record) {
            // Call the controller's "show" action
            Ext.dispatch({
                controller: myApp.controllers.products,
                action: 'show',
                id: record.getId()
            });
        }
    }
```

But now I want it to live here (to remove the disclosure button and make the whole row selectable):

```
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        itemTap: function (record) {
            alert('!!!');
            // Call the controller's "show" action
            Ext.dispatch({
                controller: myApp.controllers.products,
                action: 'show',
                id: record.getId()
            });
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
The function within the `itemTap:` listener is called (the alert is displayed), but the `'show'` action is not called in the controller as it is when the `Ext.dispatch` lived within the `onItemDisclosure:`.

Comment: are you getting javascript errors?

Comment: Other than a stupid browser caching-related error (which has now been resolved), I wasn't seeing any javascript errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are doing this inside of a list as in the other question, the itemtap event is passed 4 arguments: Ext.DataView this, Number index, Ext.Element item, Ext.EventObject e .

so you want to do something like

```
itemtap: function(dataView, index, item, e) {
    Ext.dispatch({
            controller: myApp.controllers.products,
            action: 'show',
            id: index
        });
}
```

That's assuming getId() is just giving you the record's index. If it's giving you something else, you could get the record object itself by doing

```
dataView.getStore().getAt(index) /* .getId() */
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I added another console log and found that the dispatch is actually being called, but something (I don't have access to it now) was turning up undefined. I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: It's usually helpful to use a debugger like Firebug or Chrome's built-in debugger (god help you if you're using IE) to set breakpoints in the script itself in addition to console logging.

Comment: Okay, the itemtap: event as you have it above works, but I have to ++ the index, as it seems to be indexed by 0 instead of by 1.

Comment: still does jack diddly for me, I ended up abandoning MVC to get it to work.